# Destroy function not working in Unity4

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have some code from a book I am working through but it is one written for Unity3, though what I am trying does not seem to work and wanted to put it here to get some fresh eyes on it:

```
function destroyPlayer(dpos : Vector3)
{  
   var plDeath : GameObject = Instantiate(playerDeathObj, dpos,   playerDeathObj.transform.rotation) as GameObject; 
   plDeath.animation["death"].speed = 3.5;
   yield WaitForSeconds(0.5);   
   Destroy(plDeath);    

}
```

So if i take out the yield, the animation you don't see play but it does get cleared out.  Here though as it stands the animation plays and then sticks.
  This is code from the book

http://www.deeppixel.com/unity3d-indie-developers-blueprints-book-training/

Didn't see any updates int he Errata was wondering if anyone had any suggestions what to try?

Answer (score 3):

This function returns an enumerator, so it should be used as a [coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html).

If you simply call it, everything until yield statement will be executed, then the function will be suspended until next call.

Comment: So for the author, the following would be an example of how to call: `StartCoroutine(destroyPlayer(Vector3.zero));`

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up using the fact that the Destroy takes another argument for the time to destroy the object, so I removed the yield and did this:

```
Destroy(plDeath, 0.5);
```

and it worked, go figure not sure why not this in the first place?